# Avoid handling EAssertionFailed

Tags: delphi, exception, assertions

Generally I make my exception handlers handle only very specific exceptions, so that the code doesn't try to recover from exceptions that weren't anticipated and potentially aren't recoverable.

But there are a few places where it is impossible to know ahead of time what exceptions could legitimately come up from which recovery is perfectly possible (because of calls to libraries that don't specify what exceptions they might raise). So in these special cases I do in fact trap all exceptions: `on e:Exception ...`.

But this also handles `EAssertionFailed` exceptions, which really should never be handled because they imply incorrect code.

So I've started writing exception handlers like this:

```
on e:Exception do
begin
  if e is EAssertionFailed then
  begin
    raise;
  end;

  …
```

This just seems ugly and error-prone. (What if I forget the `if e is EAssertionFailed` code?)

Is there a better way? (Should I just *never ever* use `on e:Exception …`, except in a top level handler that aborts the program?)

**Update**

I think David's comment below is correct - never use a blanket exception handler (other than to log the exception and stop the program).

The problem then becomes "How can I get a list of all exception types that are safe to handle arising from some arbitrary bit of code?" I don't think this is one that Stack Overflow can answer.

(The particular problem is a 3rd party library that reads a configuration file. There are fairly obvious exceptions for filing system errors, but the library seems to raise numerous and almost random exception types for syntax errors within the file itself. I don't think I could ever be sure that I've exhausted the possibilities. I **certainly** cannot have my application fall over because the configuration file couldn't be read!)

Comment: Ask yourself why you are writing blanket exception handlers at all. You realise you are glugging down EAbort too. And what else? My reaction is that the solution is simply to remove blanket exception handlers. The only place for blanket handlers is at the boundary between modules that do and do not support exceptions. For instance across a DLL boundary.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right about EAbort and what else…? I think I have to take your advice. See my answer below.

Comment: @IanGoldby a question for you to think about - should you handle a thrown `TObject` or not?

Comment: @user246408 I don't understand the question. Who would throw a something not descended from `Exception`? I don't think I need to worry about that possibility.

Comment: I would throw - just for fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm offering my own answer here to see what the community thinks.

The point wasn't a misunderstanding of how exception handling works in Delphi. I've summarised the particular problem in my update to the question.

My solution is going to be to convert the many different exception types the library can raise into a single type that I can handle explicitly. I'll put a blanket exception handler around the one problem call to the library. This handler will raise a new exception of a known type, to be caught explicitly higher up at the appropriate time.

(And no, the exceptions raised by the library call do not have any common base type other than Exception itself, so I really do have to catch all exceptions if I want to recover from a failure in the library call.)

*Crucially, I believe that although I cannot hope to enumerate all the exceptions that this library call could raise, I can be sure that it won't put the application into an unstable state when it raises an exception.*

**Update**

In the end I was able to use something like this:

```
on e:Exception do
begin
  if (e.ClassType = Exception) or (e is EConvertError) or
     (e is EVariantError) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('The application settings could not be loaded.');
  end
  else
  begin
    // An exception we didn't anticipate. Assume it is fatal.
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

A lot of the recoverable exceptions raised by the library are of type `Exception`, but note that only `Exception` and the *specified* descendants are handled. The others are raised indirectly by the runtime library. There might turn out to be other exceptions that should be handled too, but this seems like a good start. It's better to have the application bail out when it needn't have done so than to continue running and corrupt the user's data.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Delphi exception handling pattern is

```
  try
// Some code which may raise an exception
  except
    on E: SomeError do begin
      // Handle SomeError and derived classes
    end;
    on E: SomeOtherError do begin
      // Handle SomeOtherError and derived classes
    end;
    ...
  end;
```

it does not require the use of `on E:Exception …`.

If you don't know the exception type you should not handle it; or sometimes (ex in DLL code) you should handle ALL exceptions.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is that I can't hope to find out all of the exception classes that I should handle in this particular library call.

Comment: @IanGoldby - just ignore the exception classes you don't know; let them be handled by the top-level exception handler (which shows an error message box in GUI app). Do not try to find out and handle all exception types that can be raised - this is impossible and not needed.

Comment: I definitely don't like the idea of a top-level blanket exception handler allowing execution to continue. You'd have no idea whether the application is still in a stable state.

Comment: Why do you think that if you don't handle an exception the application is unstable? It is not so. Maybe you trying to write code that should be in `finally` block instead of `except`?

Comment: By definition, an unanticipated exception is one you didn't make proper provision for in the code where the exception originated. Even if you are meticulous with try/finally, you still cannot completely guarantee the application is still in a known and predictable state.

Comment: @IanGoldby That is paranoid programming. If you really need it you should not use nor Delphi nor Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't to use this:

```
try
  ...
except
  on EAssertionFailed do raise;
  on E: .... do ... ; // your exception
  on E: .... do ... ; // your exception
  on E: .... do ... ; // your exception
  on E: Exception do ... ; // all other exceptions
end;
```

If any of the handlers in the exception block matches the exception, control passes to the first such handler. An exception handler 'matches' an exception just in case the type in the handler is the class of the exception or an ancestor of that class.

Or you can remove `on EAssertionFailed do raise;` and `on E: Exception do ... ;` from the exception block and then exception handler will be searched in the next-most-recently entered try...except statement that has not yet exited.

Comment: That gets rid of `if e is EAssertionFailed then`, which is nice, but doesn't solve the underlying problem.